# Using Case statement with partition by by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am trying to get the following from this code If there is more than one match, find the record where LearnStartDate = LearnDelFAMDateFrom else leave blank

```
select 
ukprn, aimseqnumber, LearnRefNumber
,LearnDelFAMCode
,LearnDelFAMType
,LearnDelFAMDateFrom
,LearningStartDate
,CASE
        when rn=1 then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
        when rn <1 then ''
        when (rn =1 and rn > 1) and (LearningStartDate = LearnDelFAMDateFrom) then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
        else
        ''
        end as LearnDelFAMDateFromMOD

--,CASE row_number() over(partition by d.LearnRefNumber,d.aimseqnumber order by LearnDelFAMDateFrom)  
-- when  1  then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
-- when < 1 then '' 
-- when > 1 and (LearningStartDate = LearnDelFAMDateFrom) then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
-- else ''
--   end as     LearnDelFAMDateFromMOD2

,rn 
--,LearnDelFAMDateTo


from
(select 
     d.ukprn,d.aimseqnumber,d.LearnRefNumber,LearnDelFAMCode,LearnDelFAMType
    ,convert(varchar(10),LearnDelFAMDateFrom) as LearnDelFAMDateFrom
    ,LearnDelFAMDateTo,LearningStartDate
    ,row_number() over(partition by d.LearnRefNumber,d.aimseqnumber order by LearnDelFAMDateFrom) rn 

    from  d

    left join rp 
    on

        d.ukprn =rp.ukprn
    and d.aimseqnumber=rp.AimSeqNumber
    and d.LearnRefNumber=rp.LearnRefNumber
    and LearnDelFAMCode=rp.ApprenticeshipContractType

    left join   aecld

   on
        d.ukprn =aecld.ukprn
  and   d.aimseqnumber=aecld.AimSeqNumber
  and   d.LearnRefNumber=aecld.learnrefnumber


    where LearnDelFAMType='ACT' 

        ) as ref
```

The comment part of the code which includes case with partition by can't be run due to i cant use greater than or less than or equal sign.

If I just use case statement for the following scenario 
when (rn =1 and rn > 1) and (LearningStartDate = LearnDelFAMDateFrom) then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
This only works for the records when rn is >1 when rn=1 it doesn't work.

Comment: `when (rn = 1 and rn > 1)` makes no sense. That expression can't ever possibly be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a CTE table for this task, the ROW_NUMBER()... AS rn would be resolved and then you can use it in your case statement

```
;WITH CTE_TEMP_TABLENAME AS 
(
select 
 d.ukprn,d.aimseqnumber,d.LearnRefNumber,LearnDelFAMCode,LearnDelFAMType
,convert(varchar(10),LearnDelFAMDateFrom) as LearnDelFAMDateFrom
,LearnDelFAMDateTo,LearningStartDate
,row_number() over(partition by d.LearnRefNumber,d.aimseqnumber order by LearnDelFAMDateFrom) rn 

from  d

left join rp 
on

    d.ukprn =rp.ukprn
and d.aimseqnumber=rp.AimSeqNumber
and d.LearnRefNumber=rp.LearnRefNumber
and LearnDelFAMCode=rp.ApprenticeshipContractType

left join   aecld

on
    d.ukprn =aecld.ukprn
and   d.aimseqnumber=aecld.AimSeqNumber
and   d.LearnRefNumber=aecld.learnrefnumber


where LearnDelFAMType='ACT' 
)

select 
  ukprn
 ,aimseqnumber
 ,LearnRefNumber
 ,LearnDelFAMCode
 ,LearnDelFAMType
 ,LearnDelFAMDateFrom
 ,LearningStartDate
 ,CASE
    when rn=1 then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
    when rn <1 then ''
    when (rn =1 and rn > 1) and (LearningStartDate = LearnDelFAMDateFrom) 
 then LearnDelFAMDateFrom
    else
    ''
    end as LearnDelFAMDateFromMOD
,rn 
,LearnDelFAMDateTo
FROM CTE_TEMP_TABLENAME
```

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the tip. But it doesn't work for the scenario where rank =1 and rank > 1.

Comment: That would be a logical impossibility. Are you not looking for rank >= 1?

Comment: Glad you got there - don't forget to mark the question as resolved :)